# The best way to filter a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a dictionary of string keys and float values.

```
 mydict = {}
 mydict["joe"] = 20
 mydict["bill"] = 20.232
 mydict["tom"] = 0.0
```

I want to filter the dictionary to only include pairs that have a value greater than zero.

In C#, I would do something like this:

```
   dict = dict.Where(r=>r.Value > 0);
```

What is the equivalent code in Python?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
d = dict((k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if v > 0)
```

In Python 2.7 and up, there's nicer syntax for this:

```
d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v > 0}
```

Note that this is not strictly a filter because it does create a new dictionary.

Comment: What if you want to filter by key?

Comment: Change it to test `k` instead of `v`?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
y = filter(lambda x:dict[x] > 0.0,dict.keys())
```

the lambda is feed the keys from the dict, and compares the values in the dict for each key, against the criteria, returning back the acceptable keys.

Comment: Questioner is looking to return a dictionary, this only returns the keys of the dictionary. And it's simply less efficient/Pythonic than @kindall's answer

Comment: could be this: `d = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] > 0.0, d.items()))`

Comment: Probably want `list(filter(...))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original dictionary is `d1` you could use something like:

```
d2 = dict((k, v) for k, v in d1.items() if v > 0)
```

By the way, note that `dict` is already reserved in python.

Answer (score 0):

The `dict` constructor can take a sequence of `(key,value)` pairs, and the `iteritems` method of a dict produces a sequence of `(key,value)` pairs.  It's two great tastes that taste great together.

```
newDict = dict([item for item in oldDict.iteritems() if item[1] > 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = {}
foo["joe"] = 20
foo["bill"] = 20.232
foo["tom"] = 0.0

bar = dict((k,v) for k,v in foo.items() if v>0)
```

`dict` is a keyword in Python so I replaced it with foo.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should not use the keyword `dict` as a variable name as it pollutes the namespace, and prevents you from referencing the `dict` class in the current or embedded scope.

```
d = {}
d["joe"] = 20
d["bill"] = 20.232
d["tom"] = 0.0

# create an intermediate generator that is fed into dict constructor 
# via a list comprehension
# this is more efficient that the pure "[...]" variant
d2 = dict(((k, v) for (k, v) in d.iteritems() if v > 0)) 

print d2
# {'bill': 20.232, 'joe': 20}
```

Alternatively, you could just create the generator and iterator over it directly. This more like a "filter", because the generator only references the values in the original dict instead of making a subset copy; and hence is more efficient than creating a new dictionary :

```
filtered = ((k, v) for (k, v) in d.iteritems() if v > 0)

print filtered 
# <generator object <genexpr> at 0x034A18F0>

for k, v in filtered:
    print k, v

# bill 20.232
# joe 20
```