# How to find if in created dictionary the chosen sequence has two aa letters?

Tags: python, dictionary, find, key

Lets say I have a dictionary. Is it possible to use the input function to enter the key and get the True for its specific value:

dictionaryOne = {
"ABCD" : "aatttgggtcatcg",
"SSEE" : "atgcccgta",
"GTAD" : "atgccggaaa"
}

I tried using if and else  including find function but I am very new in this and don't know how to combine everything.

Comment: you mean to find the key the has aa letters in values?

Comment: What output are you expecting?  Please give sample output.

Comment: Oh sorry, I need a true or false statement if my chosen key in its value has "aa".

Comment: Yeah, thank you! This is pretty close, however, perhaps it is possible to use the input function to enter the key and get the True for its specific value?

Comment: `"aa" in dictionaryOne[key]` will return true if "aa" is in the chosen key's value, or false otherwise.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! This works. I am very new here but when I will have enough points for voting I will definitely upvote your solution. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this to determine whether your value has `aa`. I'm assuming you only to need to print the bool value

```
is_exist = False
for key, val in dictionaryOne.items():
    if 'aa' in val:
        is_exist = True
    print(f'{key}: {is_exist}')
```

UPDATE:

```
# Gets user input
name = input("enter the key: ")

dictionaryOne = { "ABCD" : "aatttgggtcatcg", "SSEE" : "atgcccgta", "GTAD" : "atgccggaaa" }

try:
    val = True if 'aa' in dictionaryOne.get(name) else False    
    print(val)
except Exception as k:
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{key: val for key, val in dictionaryOne.items() if "aa" in val}
```

[The best way to filter a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425046/the-best-way-to-filter-a-dictionary-in-python)